# How to get the UDID of a dead iOS device?

Tags: ios, provisioning, udid

I have dead, lost, stolen, etc. iOS devices on my developer account and I've used all 100 slots. I have serial numbers for these devices, but do not know the UDIDs to remove them. Can I do anything but grovel to Apple?

Comment: didn't you name the devices properly for the dev account?..

Comment: Of the 100, I added 4. Those 4 have perfectly descriptive names.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3):

build a dummy provision file and include all devices from your portal on it .. open the provision with TextEdit .. find the key "ProvisionedDevices" under this key you find all the devices UDID .. since you have the working Devices UDID find it and mark them .. finally the un marked ID's will be your Black List :)

Comment: That would be workable if I had physical access to these devices. They are very geographically dispersed.